# Installing Quojs

Tags: javascript, quojs

I'm trying to install Quojs, a gestures library but I got the following error :

```
TypeError: $$(...).tap is not a function
```

Any idea what I should do to get it work ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>The Touc Project</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>TOUC !</h1>
    <!-- js -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/quojs/quo.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $$('h1').tap(function(e){
        console.log('tap');
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Seem to be specific to 3.X.X version, the 2.3.6 quo.js works fine

Answer (score 0):

Check the source url of Quojs and try  this instead

```
$$('h1').tap(function(){
    console.log('tap');
});
```

Comment: Still have the same error, you can try to see why there : https://jsfiddle.net/9qn0jegr/1/